# How do I control permissions at a column level in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is there a way to create to radio button on a SharePoint List that only one user from a group can click?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft product group members have said, repeatedly and in all kinds of forums, that column-level security is not supported and when asked about future versions of SharePoint have said that no this will never happen as there are too many performance implications.

The best way to approach this would be to attach an Infopath form to the list and have different views on the form for different users.

[Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff961896(v=office.14).aspx) the MSDN documentation on the subject to help get you started.